# PyDev and Django inside virtual environment

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev, virtualenv

I've set my virtual environment through console and than with pip installed Django into it. I'd really like now to open and run this folder/project/virtualenv inside of PyDev, but I don't know how. In PyDev I can only start new Django project, which hasn't isolated environment...

You know what I mean?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the Python interpreter used by the project to the interpreter in the virtualenv. The Pydev manual has more information on how to [configure the interpreter](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#id3).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but it looks like I don't get relative paths. Or this doesn't even matters?

Answer (score 0):

If this works anything like iPython, you will need to install PyDev inside of your virtual environment. IE:

```
pip install ipython
```